# Linq join from 2 difference list

Tags: c#, linq

I have class A as below

```
class A {
 int id,
 string state,
 string name
}
```

And 2 List

```
List<A> l1;

A (1, "S1", "N1")
A (2, "S2", "")
A (3, "S3", "N3")
A (4, "S4", "N4")

List<A> l2;
A (11, "S2", "N21")
A (12, "S2", "N22")
```

Now I want the expect l1 result like this, it look like a left join and replace the empty value from l1 with value from l2 if "name is empty".

```
A (1, "S1", "N1")
A (11, "S2", "N21")
A (12, "S2", "N22")
A (3, "S3", "N3")
A (4, "S4", "N4")
```

I have tried get the result of inner join and l1.add(inner_join_results) but it also contain the empty value. Appreciate any help or suggestion

Comment: Your code won't compile. You say if "state is null" but it looks like the `name` is an empty string, unless "N1", "N3" and "N4" are `state` values and not `name` values. Can you make it clearer? How do you know which part of `l2` to include - is it always the whole thing?

Comment: Basically, will 'replace' name on l1 with l2(possibly a list) if 'match' on state

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```cs
var result =
   from i1 in l1
   join i2 in l2 on i1.state equals i2.state into j
   from i2 in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new A
   {
      id = i2 == null ? i1.id : string.IsNullOrEmpty(i1.name) ? l2.id : t1.id,
      state = i1.state,
      name = i2 == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i1.name) ? i1.name : l2.name
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a few extension methods I already had:

```
public static bool IsEmpty(this string s) => (s.Length == 0);
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this string s) => (s.Length > 0);
public static IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T item) => new[] { item };
```

You can filter the list by empty names:

```
var ans = l1.SelectMany(anL => anL.name.IsNotEmpty()
                                    ? anL.AsSingleton()
                                    : l2.Where(anL2 => anL2.state == anL.state))
            .ToList();
```

Alternatively, a bit more performant is to write a custom extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T,bool> testFn, Func<T,IEnumerable<T>> replFn) {
    foreach (var e in src) {
        if (testFn(e))
            foreach (var e2 in replFn(e))
                yield return e2;
        else
            yield return e;
    }
    
}
```

Then your answer is:

```
var ans2 = l1.Replace(anL => anL.name.IsEmpty(), anL => l2.Where(anL2 => anL.state == anL2.state)).ToList();
```